# Android service not starting via alarm

Tags: android, service, android-context

Is there any problem with launching a service via an Alarm's
BroadcastReceiver's onReceive? My service never has it's onCreate or
onStart method called.

My Alarm's receiver gets a wakelock, calls context.startService(new
Intent(context, FmiDaemon.class)); (context given via onRecieve
parameter),  waits 3 seconds, then releases the lock.

My service has 2 methods, onCreate and onStart. onCreate gets another
wakelock, the end of onStart releases the wakelock, and calls
"stopSelf". Both methods are supposed to send data to a log, but never
do since they're never called.

Where is the problem? Is that a bad "context" to use? Is onCreate and
onStart the wrong methods to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but in case anyone else has this problem:

1) Add a log entry to the start of your receiver class onReceive. If your log doesn't show this message, you don't have the alarm setup right or your receiver isn't in the in the manifest file.

2) Add your receiver class to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

3) My startService() looks as follows:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, MyServiceClass.class);

context.startService(newIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this within the application tag of your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<service android:name="com.yourpackagetoyourserviceclass.FmiDaemon"/>
```